# Ubuntu software not working

Tags: software-center

Non technical 65 year old woman. Loaded Ubuntu 16.10 on old windows laptop. Ubuntu software center 3.20.1 does not work. Can momentarily see apps store then new window which only lists current software. Have tried solutions none work. Thanks.

- List item

Comment: Could you briefly describe (or point us to) the solutions you have already tried?

Comment: 16.10 is no longer supported. Try 16.04 or 17.10.

Comment: +1 simply for your background and the bravery to deal with Ubuntu _and_ trying to get help here. Don't get me wrong, but I find this just admirable.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it does not seem like Software Center is broken.

Support for Ubuntu 16.10 ended about 8 months ago. There is simply no longer any new software available for Software Center to display. Those software repositories were closed and withdrawn (that's what happens when support ends).

It's unwise to keep using 16.10 for much longer - your system has not received any security updates for 8 months, and may be vulnerable to published exploits.

You have three options:

1. You can backup your data (mail, photos, browser settings, etc) and install **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**, which is fully supported for **three more years**. It will look and feel very much like your current 16.10 system.
2. You can wait until late April 2018, and then backup-your-data-and-install the newly-released **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**, which will be fully supported for **five more years**. The look-and-feel will be slightly different (slightly, not hugely), as the system has evolved a bit in two years.
3. You can backup-and-install the current Ubuntu 17.10, which is supported for only six more *months*. I don't recommend this option for you, as the same problem (end of support) will re-occur soon.

Regardless of the option you choose, preserving your data is very important. Installing a new release of Ubuntu is rather serious surgery - there is chance of serious complications. Those complications, while rare, might lead to complete data loss while leaving your PC physically unharmed.

This site has the stories and tears of some folks who suffered just such rare complications and lost all their photos and emails and work. Don't let it happen to you - take a few minutes and preserve your data before starting any of those options.

Comment: or you could press ALT+F2 and type "update-manager -cd" to update to a non-lts, like 17.04

Comment: @YoranJansen yes, that would seem to fall under option #3. Different method, similar result.

Comment: This is easier because you do not need to reinstall or backup or burn, just update